# Не пойму причину не работоспособности регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript

```
var myPattern = /^(.*)/ig;
var matchStation = mass.filter(function (station) {
    if (station.search(myPattern) > 0) return station;
});
matchStation.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

mass - массив из 160 станций. НЕ работает именно `search()` (массив `matchStation`  всегда пустой). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле `.search` работает.

Указанное регулярное выражение, фактически соответствует началу строки, и `search` будет возвращать `0` во всех случаях.

Из-за этого проверка `(station.search(myPattern) > 0)` всегда ложная и из функции переданной в `filter` всегда возвращается `undefined`, что соответствует `false`.

Поэтому результирующий массив всегда пуст.

Comment: не пойму, почему  search возвращает 0? ведь патерну `/^(.*)/ig` соответствует любая строка. Разве не 1 должно возвращать?

Comment: Понял ошибку, спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Я думал что если он нашел совпадение то возвращает 1

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, нет, search, так же как и IndexOf возвращает индекс найденной подстроки, или -1 если ничего не найдено